Loading more posts in Next js Server Components
I have a next js server component that is rendering a 5 recent posts from a cms and the page is using SSG with revalidate every 10min . To load next 5 posts and so on I am using client component with SWR and skipping first 5 static posts. Problem with this approach is when i add new post in CMS I can get a duplicate  because I am recieving a fresh data on client but not on a server component until the revalidating is done. Is there a way to load more without triggering dynamic rendering?
Here is a Server component...
   export async function getData(category: string, nums: number) {
   const res = await getPostsByCategory(category, nums);

    if (!res) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data..");
    }

    return res;
   }

   const PostList = async ({
    category,
    amount,
    }: {
    category: string;
    amount: number;
    }) => {

   const data = await getData(category, amount);
     return (
      <div>{....rest of the code}</div>
      );
   };

   export default PostList;

